# AsyncTask not waiting for an object to be created before completion

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an object, `MyObject`, that populates itself with some random numbers. It doesn't take very long and is seemingly instant. However, these values are used on the UI and on occasion it isn't completely ready when the UI is building.

I've created an `AsyncTask` that is used to instantiate the object and it's at the end of this post.

However `doInBackground(...)` doesn't instantiate the object completely before `onPostExecute(...)` is called when it is in this fashion.

```
protected MyObject doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    // this may take a few moments and cause a null reference
    // so make a task
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    return obj;
}
```

I've also tried to use a flag to signify completion, but it doesn't appear to guarantee either.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
while (obj.isComplete() == false) {
    // do nothing. Wait for completion
}

return obj;
```

Inside of `MyObject` is simple

```
public MyObject() {
    createValues(); // entire object created with this
    this.mComplete = true;
}
```

It fails less, but still does. `createValues()` uses an `ArrayList` for part of its calculations if that is contributing to the race condition.

Below is an example `MyFragment` that uses the task in `methodCall()`.

**Question** How do I simply wait until `MyObject` is completely instantiated to end?

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyFragment.setupFragment(MyFragment.java:95)
    at MyFragment.onTaskComplete(MyFragment.java:143)
    at MyTask.onPostExecute(MyTask.java:37)
    at MyTask.onPostExecute(MyTask.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyTask.OnTaskComplete {
    private MyObject mMyObject;

    // ...

    public void methodCall() {
        // generate puzzle and set it up in the background
        MyTask task = new MyTask(this);
        task.execute();
    }

    function void setupFragment() {
            // null pointer exception here
            // mMyObject is not initiated yet and only some times
            // values is an array of integers
        int example = this.mMyObject.values[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(MyObject obj) {
        // returned from MyTask
        this.mMyObject = obj;
        this.setupFragment(); 
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class MyObjectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyObject> {
    public static interface OnTaskComplete {
        public abstract void onTaskComplete(MyObject obj);
    }
    static final String TAG = "MyObjectTask";

    private OnTaskComplete mListener;

    public MyObjectTask(OnTaskComplete listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected MyObject doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // this may take a few moments and cause a null reference
        // so make a task
        return new MyObject();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyObject obj) {
        this.mListener.onTaskComplete(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: `mListener` can be `null`

Comment: Good point. I'll make sure to capture that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should be completely fine if you are not creating any new threads inside your object when creating it.

You have added a callback which you need to fist set before executing the task and then it will be triggered when the AsyncTask exits (doInBackground finishes and your post execute is called).

So from what i am seeing in your code there is no way the constructor doesn't finish and your object is returned in the callback.

So check if possibly something throws an Exception in your object in the method createValues.

Do you have a stacktrace of the exception that happens?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added my usage of the task to the post and it get's a null pointer in the `setupFragment()` method. I've added the related stacktrace.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I'm using an `ArrayList` internally in `MyObject` if that causes issues in threads. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Your object is not declared as an array yet you are still accessing it as such. i think the issue is somewhere in how you have setup things in my object. everything else looks fine. if you are using an array list you need to get the value as list.get(position). the way you have it now is like a regular array not an arraylist as you state

Comment: I'm using an ArrayList internal to `MyObject` for calculating random numbers. The I missed a part in my post. It is `mMyObject.values[0]` where values is _int[]_

Comment: Well, I did more intense logcat logging and it seems that on occasion doInBackground never finishes. I spend time tracing all of that and at one point one of the random numbers caused an infinite loop. Since you took the time to respond and the answer is a correct anwser anyway, I'm marking it the answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you object on onPreExecute method from AsyncTask. So, when doInBackground was called you object will be already created. In that point, you can just **call the method to create values**.

```
public class MyObjectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyObject> {
    public static interface OnTaskComplete {
        public abstract void onTaskComplete(MyObject obj);
    }

    static final String TAG = "MyObjectTask";

    private OnTaskComplete mListener;
    private MyObject myObject;

    public MyObjectTask(OnTaskComplete listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myObject = new MyObject();
    }

    @Override
    protected MyObject doInBackground(Void... unused) {
         // this may take a few moments and cause a null reference
        // so make a task
        myObject.createValues();
       return myObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyObject obj) {
        this.mListener.onTaskComplete(obj);
    }
}
```